# Is there any twitter authentication for flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

so I want users to be able to sign up with their twitter account on my flutter website.

I've found this package (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_twitter) but I've tried it and it does not work on flutter web, only on mobiles.

So, do I have to make this auth myself? If so, how could i do that?

Answer (score 2):

For Flutter Web, the [flutter_twitter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_twitter) package does NOT work, unfortunately. However, using [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) and [firebase_core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core) will work for Flutter Web:

```
Future<bool> signInWithTwitter() async {
  final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
      .signInWithPopup(TwitterAuthProvider());
  return userCredential.user != null;
}
```

Before you can use that, you need to initialize Firebase for the App:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

Don't forget to listen to the user changes, for example:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
    .authStateChanges()
    .listen((User? user) {
  if (user == null) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
});
```

Also, make sure that you set the callback URL in Twitter's "Authentication settings" to something like:

```
https://[YOURAPPNAME].firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler
```

and that your Firebase Authentications include Twitter as a provider.

Answer (score 1):

You can use firebase Authentication sign-in method with twitter

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but how could I get the twitter credentials ?

Comment: I mean, there's no signInWithTwitter method with firebase auth

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [Firebase Auth Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) provided by the Firebase team.
This plugin support Google, Email and Password, Phone, Anonymously, GitHub, Facebook, and Twitter authentication.

Or you can use [Flutter_Twitter package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_twitter), [TwitterAPI package](https://pub.dev/packages/twitter_api) provided by the community.

Hope it will help